# What exactly is required in order to create custom WebChat for Twilio Flex?

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-flex, twilio-taskrouter

I would like to understand how exactly I would go about creating a completely custom webchat for a website.

The reason why is because I realize that there are some limits to the degree to which I can customize the WebChat that is out-of-the-box, especially using JS alone.

I went about viewing the instructions for how to setup WebChat using the instructions, and I was just not able to figure out how to use the npm approach, only the CDN (using asp.net core and a separate website is using Wordpress). which sort of limited the degree to which I could make customizations to the UI.

I really wish I was able to use the npm package, but unfortunately the two web frameworks that the sites were build with (asp.net core, and WordPress) didnt have a clear way of accomplishing this. I posted about this issue previously with someone just saying "Its easy, just search online" . My search didnt result in anything helpful, unfortunately.

If someone can provide us engineers interested in making tweeks with clear instructions or an example of using javascript alone to add/remove components, I wouldnt have to build the web chat from scratch. There is just very limited documentation I feel for this. It almost appears that the app needs to be a react app, just to host the webchat if trying to customize using the extensibilty options twilio flex team provided.

Any insight is appreciated. What I am expecting is someone saying "Unfortunately, completing customizations using NPM is only available if the web  framework is react based". or something like that. Is this true or false? If it is false, how exactly can I replace a component using javascript alone?